# Aligning HTML Buttons Horizontally (Not Using CSS)

Tags: html

I'm writing an email campaign in Ascendify and need to center 5 html linked buttons horizontally.I do not have access to the CSS, so I need to just do it with html code. I'm really struggling in figuring this out, any feedback would be appreciated. Here's the code:

```
    <div id="buttonGroup">
<div style="text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./engineering/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Engineering</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./engineering/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Engineering</a></div>

<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./hr-recruiting/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">HR & Recruiting</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./hr-recruiting/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">HR &amp; Recruiting</a></div>

<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./product-design/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Product & Design</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./product-design/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Product &amp; Design</a></div>

<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./sales-marketing/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Sales & Marketing</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./sales-marketing/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Sales &amp; Marketing</a></div>

<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./women-tech/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Women In Tech</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./women-tech/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Women In Tech</a></div>
```

Comment: How exactly do you want them aligned? The five of them in the center, in each line, or of the five of then in the center of its own line?

Comment: Five centered on one line.

Comment: *“Not Using CSS”* – But you’re using CSS there? I don’t get it.

Comment: @poke I believe he meant not using a CSS stylesheet file, even though he is using inline styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a `display: inline-block;` to your div's style inline. That way, for each of your divs, you just have to add this style tag, so it would be something like this:

```
 <div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
```

You have to do it in all of your divs, otherwise it won't work.

In your code, it would be like this:

```html
<div id="buttonGroup" style="text-align:center;">
<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./engineering/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
<w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
<center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Engineering</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./engineering/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Engineering</a></div>

<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./hr-recruiting/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
<w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
<center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">HR & Recruiting</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./hr-recruiting/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">HR &amp; Recruiting</a></div>

<div style="display: inline-block; text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./product-design/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
<w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
<center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Product & Design</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./product-design/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Product &amp; Design</a></div>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div id="buttonGroup" style="text-align:center;">

<div style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./sales-marketing/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
 <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
 <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Sales & Marketing</center>
</v:roundrect>
   <![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./sales-marketing/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Sales &amp; Marketing</a></div>

<div style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;">&nbsp;</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;text-align: center;"><!--[if mso]>
<v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./women-tech/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
<w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
<center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Women In Tech</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./women-tech/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Women In Tech</a></div>
</div>
```

You can learn more about the display style in here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time to respond. This worked almost perfectly. The only issue is that there wasnt enough space on a single line to fit them all. So I put a break after the first three and now the two on the next line are left justified instead of centered. I've already asked a lot, but what would I do to center these?

Comment: Try putting those inside another `<div id="buttonGroup" style="text-align:center;">`.

Comment: @G.Elliott It displayed something diferent from this? http://i.imgur.com/i59RUfH.png

Comment: It displayed like that...until I ran it.  The constraints of the email format template (probably the CSS I can't access) created weird spacing and wrapped the buttons.  So I put a break in after the first 3, and now the spacing is fine for the first three, centered on the top line.  And I'm working on centering the last two, centered on the second line.

Comment: @G.Elliott You want something like this, then? Just tell me so and i will edit my answer: http://imgur.com/FpTi5Fy

Comment: Yes, but with a space between the two rows, so that the'yre not touching.

Comment: Ok. Just a moment.

Comment: @G.Elliott Check my answer's snippet again. And if i helped you, please accept my answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Add a style attribute

```
<button style='display: inline-block;'> </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Twop options for achiving expeccted result

```
<div style="text-align: center;float:left"
```

Other option using display:inline as mentioned by Blaze349

Codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pPWJVm

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. The only issue is that therewasnt enough space on a single line to fit them all.  So I put a break after the first three and now the two on the next line are left justified instead of centered. I've already asked a lot, but what would I do to center these?

Answer (score 1):

You currently have 5 buttons stacked on top of each other because each anchor is wrapped in a div, which is `display:block` by default, meaning it fills the entire horizontal space for its line.

I would either remove the `div` tags wrapping the anchors altogether and just have 5 anchor tags next to each other, or change the div tags to `span` tags, which are inline by default.

You can also remove the extraneous `div` tags with non-breaking spaces and use `style="margin-right: 10px;"` (or whatever value looks good) on each anchor or wrapping span to give space between the anchors.

Also, you can move the "text-align: center" style to the outermost wrapping div and it will center all the buttons and their text for you without having to do that on each child element.

```html
    <div id="buttonGroup" style="text-align: center;">
<span><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./engineering/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Engineering</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./engineering/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Engineering</a></span>

<span><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./hr-recruiting/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">HR & Recruiting</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./hr-recruiting/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">HR &amp; Recruiting</a></span>

<span><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./product-design/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Product & Design</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./product-design/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Product &amp; Design</a></span>

<span><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./sales-marketing/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Sales & Marketing</center>
  </v:roundrect>
  <![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./sales-marketing/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Sales &amp; Marketing</a></span>
  
  <span><!--[if mso]>
  <v:roundrect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./women-tech/signup" style="height:40px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:125px;" arcsize="10%" strokecolor="#1393ec" fillcolor="#219bed">
    <w:anchorlock></w:anchorlock>
    <center style="color:#ffffff;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;">Women In Tech</center>
  </v:roundrect>
<![endif]--><a href="http://careers.grayscalable.com./women-tech/signup" style="background-color:#219bed;border:1px solid #1393ec;border-radius:4px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;line-height:40px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:125px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;">Women In Tech</a></span>
```